# Behat 3 + Symfony 3 Context with namespace doesn't work, when without works

Tags: symfony, autoload, behat, psr-4, psr-0

I have the following *catalogs structure*:

```
composer.json
behat.yml
src
|--AppBundle
   |--Features
      |--example.feature
      |--Context
         |--FeatureContext.php
```

And the following *behat.yml*

```
default:
  autoload:
    '': 'src/AppBundle/Features/Context'
  suites:
    default:
      paths: ['src/AppBundle/Features']
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
          session: '@session'
    # and extensions standard for Symphony
```

And *FeatureContext.php* contains

```
<?php

//namespace AppBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{   ...   }
```

There is commented *namespace*. When I run behat, now context is found correctly. When I uncomment *namespace* there occurs error:

> [Behat\Behat\Context\Exception\ContextNotFoundException]
>   `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.

How to make it working when *namespace* in *FeatureContext.php* is uncommented? I do not know much about PSR-0 and PSR-4, but if problem can be connected with this i append fragment of *composer.json*.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

I looking for best practices of coding, so if I am doing something in bad way I vote up for appropriate suggestion.

- I seem I should have *namespace* in *FeatureContext.php*, shouldn't I?
- I seem I shouldn't use *PSR-0* in *composer.json*, should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example below. Full example is here: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/l41o/testing-a-basic-auth-symfony-api-with-behat3 You can also find more behat examples here: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat

Note 1: You can access the `session` in context files directly so no need to inject it. You might need to use `implements KernelAwareContext` or `implements KernelAwareInterface` or `implements ContainerAwareInterface`. Just check the blog posts above.

Note 2: You don't need `autoload-dev` in composer.sjon at all. Get rid of it.

**composer.json**

Note: Use new versions!

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "3.0.15",
        "behat/symfony2-extension": "2.1.0",
        "behat/mink": "1.7.0",
        "behat/mink-extension": "2.1.0",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "1.3.0"
    },
}
```

**behat.yml**

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://your_local_app_domain.com/app_test.php/
            sessions:
                symfony2:
                    symfony2: ~
    suites:
        api:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: ApplicationApiBundle
            mink_session: symfony2
            contexts:
                - Application\ApiBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext:
                    param: 'whatever'
```

**FeatureContext.php**

```
namespace Application\ApiBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    private $param;

    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
    }

    ......
}
```

**Test**

```
$ bin/behat --suite=api @ApplicationApiBundle/YourFeature.feature
```